# How to containerize legacy app with PHP version 5.4.x?

Tags: php, docker, legacy

I am new to PHP development and stuck for two days just to set up the PHP version in my local. I am trying to continue the legacy app that builds using PHP version 5.4.45. Firstly, I have been attempting to install PHP version 5.4.45 on my MacOS Ventura (13.4.1) devices from [these sources](https://prototype.php.net/versions/5.4/install/source). After I extract, `configure`, and `make` it seems that it has compatibility issues with my devices.

Since I have been stuck all day, I try to build a container to run the legacy app using Docker. I follow [this guide](https://prototype.php.net/versions/5.4/install/docker) and here is my docker file:

```
FROM php:5.4-apache-stretch

RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli opcache

ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php.ini
```

and execute the docker command `docker build -t first-php-docker .` and it yields the error `failed to solve: php:5.4-apache-stretch: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/php/manifests/5.4-apache-stretch": EOF` and it seems the source is doesn't exist anymore.

Question:

- How to make sure whether the `php:5.4-apache-stretch` image still exists or not?

  - If it still exists, how to build a container with that image as the base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently only one PHP 5.4 + Apache image available on Docker Hub

[php:5.4-apache](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/php/5.4-apache/images/sha256-298f2295509309262b0daaa27e15e3682437d0210128f66d482381255b907582?context=explore).

This image is only built for the AMD64 platform so you'll need to specify that if you're building on an M1 / M2 Mac.

You should also use the pre-configured `PHP_INI_DIR` environment variable when adding your `php.ini` file. See [Configuration](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/php#configuration).

```dockerfile
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 php:5.4-apache

# ...

ADD php.ini "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"
```

Without the above `--platform` specification, you will constantly get warnings like

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested

Note, this uses a Debian Jessie base image.

Comment: I am building on M1 Mac, should I replace the --platform arguments with `linux/arm64`?

Comment: @sempraEdic no. The image is only available on the `linux/amd64` platform. My answer is to be taken literally

Comment: Now the problem happened for this line `ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php.ini`, since it is using `linux/amd64` platform, what to modify for this line?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what that means. There should be no issue adding a file

Comment: It yields error `failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 28bd.....: "/php.ini": not found`. Does it means `php:5.4-apache` image doesn't contain `php.ini` file?

Comment: It's telling you that your current build context (ie the current directory) doesn't have a `php.ini` file. The issue is the source, not the destination

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254518/discussion-between-sempraedic-and-phil).